# Null value causing crash even with if/else statement?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having the strangest issue. I'm using the below code to display the profile photo of a logged in user (I'm retrieving the image from a field in my Drupal database).

**.m**

```
//USER PHOTO

    NSDictionary *user = [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user];
    NSString *secondLink = user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];

    NSLog(@"This is second link %@", secondLink);

 if([secondLink length]>0) {


    NSString *ImageURL = secondLink;
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
 //   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
   self.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

  } else {

   NSString *ImageURL = @"http://url.com/default.png";
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Naturally, if secondLink is null (or empty, e.g. no photo has been uploaded), I receive the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArray0
>   objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x14f602fe0'

I thought I solved this issue with the if/else statement, but apparently not. How can I fix this?

Cheers!

Comment: Which line is the crash on?  Based on the message it seems like it would be on the `NSString *secondLink = ...` line and one of your intermediate values that you are using like it is a dictionary is actually an array.

Comment: @dan NSString *secondLink = user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"]; - This is the line that crashes, but ONLY when field_photo_path is empty. I need it to not crash when it's empty lol.

Comment: It wouldn't crash if it was empty - something there contains something that you don't expect. I suggest using variables for all the things you access so you have a chance of debugging it.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line it's crashing on, then inspect the `user` dictionary to see if the data is there that you'd expect. One of those subscripts is likely not what you're expecting it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *secondLink = user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

You need to verify that the user dictionary is valid before reading that far into it.

```
if (user[@"field_photo_path"]) {

     // you can look for [@"und"] here
     // providing it is a dictionary and not an array
     if([user[@"field_photo_path"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){
         if (user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"]) {
            // etc
         }
    }
}
```

You can reduce this nested code by modelling a `User` class as an `NSObject` subclass and include methods in that class to parse this data safely, allowing you to only write this validation code in one place.

**Edit**
As mentioned in a comment:

If the data in `user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"]` is an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSArray` you cannot access it with `[0]` and will get your crash. You access `NSArray's` with an index (`array[0]`, `array[1]` etc) and an `NSDictionary` with a key (`dict[@"name"]`, `dict[@"und"]` etc)

Comment: Okay, I'm confused lol. Sorry, I'm kind of a newb. I don't understand how this code will keep the error from occurring? The fields are returned fine, and the error only occurs when data isn't present?

Comment: Yes the error is occurred when accessing an object which is not there or wrong type object  please try my answer I have tried to correct your code, it might resolve the problem

Comment: @TarunSeerayour code is not enough to prevent the crash. If the data in user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"] is an NSDictionary and not an NSArray you cannot access it with [0] and will get your crash. You access NSArray's with an index (array[0], array[1] etc) and an NSDictionary with a key (dict[@"name"] dict[@"und"] etc)

Comment: @TarunSeera The catch you provided works - is this not the best way to handle it? Cause I'm loving it haha

Comment: It is but for dynamic value you must use above code I am correcting it the try catch is always best way but its skip subsequent block after getting exception

Comment: @Brittany That is not the best way to handle this. Your incoming data is not parsing because it is returning something that you are not expecting. By wrapping with try/catch you are not solving the problem; you are ignoring it

Comment: Please try the first block now

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to put check on on your key's

//USER PHOTO

```
NSDictionary *user = [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user];
if (user[@"field_photo_path"]) {


    if ([user[@"field_photo_path"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

        if (user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"]) {
            if ([user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"]isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {

                if ([user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"] count]>0) {

                    if (user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"]) {

                        if ([user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]){

                            NSString *secondLink = user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];

                            NSLog(@"This is second link %@", secondLink);

                            if([secondLink length]>0) {


                                NSString *ImageURL = secondLink;
                                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
                                //   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                                self.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

                            } else {

                                NSString *ImageURL = @"http://url.com/default.png";
                                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
                                self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can also use try catch block to avoid crashing

```
@try {
    //USER PHOTO

    NSDictionary *user = [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user];
    NSString *secondLink = user[@"field_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];

    NSLog(@"This is second link %@", secondLink);

    if([secondLink length]>0) {


        NSString *ImageURL = secondLink;
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
        //   self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        self.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    } else {

        NSString *ImageURL = @"http://url.com/default.png";
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    //Handle expecption
}
@finally {

}
```

Comment: Tried your first block of code, error still occurred :/

Comment: No problem can you print your NSDictionary *user and share the value so that We can check what data is exactly there ,also try the @try block code,you might trying to get the key value form array which is not possible i

Comment: I've commented my answer regarding this - it is not enough to check for existence / count. You need to check the *type* of the object

Comment: Please share your dictionary data, code is not enough to check the problem , share the NSDictionary *user = [[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] user data what value is there in it